# Trouble connecting to a remote JMS queue from one wildfly 10 app to another

Tags: java, jms, wildfly-10, message-driven-bean

I have two Wildfly 10 servers running and had a JMS queue working with Jboss and Hornet. There I used netty connectors so I scrapped all the config and got the default config for messaging on wildfy 10. I cannot get JMS to work properly.
I haven't really found any good documentation or examples doing what I want. I hope someone can help out.

**Serverside**

I have set the wildfly 10 server on the serverside to use standalone-full.xml to get the messaging extension.

Here is the standalone-full.xml content related to messaging (default without adding anything)

```
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

Here is the code i made for defining the queue and receiving messages using a MessageDrivenBean:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:app/jms/queue/SecServerQ")
})
@JMSDestinationDefinition(
  name = "java:app/jms/queue/SecServerQ",
  interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue",
  destinationName = "SecServerQ"
)
public class SecServerMDB implements MessageListener
{
  public void onMessage(Message message)
  {
    // my code here
  }
}
```

I can see the queue in the wildfly console:

[image]

**Clientside**

I have a standalone-full.xml messaging section equal to the serverside configfile on my clientserver also.

Here is the code I use trying to get a connection to the serverside JMS queue.

```
public class WildFlyJmsQueueSender
{
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.class);

  public final static String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
  public final static String JMS_QUEUE_JNDI="jms/queue/SecServerQ";
  public final static String JMS_USERNAME="jmsuser";       //  The role for this user is "guest" in ApplicationRealm
  public final static String JMS_PASSWORD="jms2017Pwd!";
  public final static String WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL="http-remoting://secserver.mydomain.com:8080";

  public void send(IpcoJmsMessage msg, String msgType) throws NamingException, JMSException {

    Context namingContext = null;

    try {
      namingContext = getInitialContext();

      log.debug("Attempting to acquire connection factory {}", JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
      ConnectionFactory conFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
      log.debug("Found connection factory {} in JNDI", JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);

      log.debug("Attempting to acquire destination {}", JMS_QUEUE_JNDI);
      Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(JMS_QUEUE_JNDI);
      log.debug("Found destination {} in JNDI", JMS_QUEUE_JNDI);

      try (JMSContext context = conFactory.createContext(JMS_USERNAME, JMS_PASSWORD)) {
        ObjectMessage objMsg = context.createObjectMessage();
        objMsg.setObject(msg);
        objMsg.setStringProperty("msgType", msgType);

        log.info("Sending message with content msg={}, msgType={}", msg, msgType);

        context.createProducer().send(destination, objMsg);
      }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      log.error("NamingException: {} {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
      if(namingContext != null) {
        try {
          namingContext.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context=null;
    try {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
      props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL);
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, JMS_USERNAME);
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, JMS_PASSWORD);
      context = new InitialContext(props);

      log.debug("Got initial Context: "+context);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return context;
  }

}
```

Here is the exception I get in the client:

```
14:11:04.965 DEBUG [LoggerProviders.java:158] - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
14:11:04.966 INFO  [Version.java:61] - WildFly Naming version 1.0.0.Beta13
14:11:04.969 DEBUG [WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:82] - Got initial Context: javax.naming.InitialContext@2c7d3911
14:11:04.969 DEBUG [WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:42] - Attempting to acquire connection factory jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
14:11:05.033 INFO  [Xnio.java:95] - XNIO version 3.5.0.Beta2
14:11:05.043 INFO  [NioXnio.java:57] - XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.0.Beta2
14:11:05.069 DEBUG [WorkerThread.java:433] - Started channel thread 'XNIO-1 Accept', selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2883da14
14:11:05.069 DEBUG [WorkerThread.java:433] - Started channel thread 'XNIO-1 I/O-1', selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@338779b1
14:11:05.081 INFO  [EndpointImpl.java:97] - JBoss Remoting version 5.0.0.Beta19
14:11:05.087 DEBUG [WorkerThread.java:433] - Started channel thread 'Remoting (anonymous) I/O-1', selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5375fba8
14:11:05.087 DEBUG [WorkerThread.java:433] - Started channel thread 'Remoting (anonymous) Accept', selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@331af02b
14:11:05.141 INFO  [Version.java:57] - ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.0.Beta33
14:11:05.382 ERROR [WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:60] - NamingException: {}WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host
javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:65) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:109) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:99) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:108) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:78) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:64) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144) ~[wildfly-naming-client-1.0.0.Beta13.jar:1.0.0.Beta13]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at no.ipco.common.WildFlyJmsQueueSender.send(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:43) ~[ipco-common-jmsclient-0.1.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

First I dropped using the @JMSDestinationDefinition in the MessageDrivenBean serverside.
Instead I defined the queue using the jboss-cli.

My standalone-full.xml config file now has the following line added

```
<jms-queue name="SecServerQ" entries="jms/queue/SecServerQ java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/SecServerQ"/>
```

On the clientside I switched the port. I tried to telnet to 8080 (old port) and there was no opening there, so I tried 28080 instead. Modifying clientcode to:

```
public final static String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
public final static String JMS_QUEUE_JNDI="jms/queue/SecServerQ";
public final static String JMS_USERNAME="jmsuser";       //  The role for this user is "guest" in ApplicationRealm
public final static String JMS_PASSWORD="jms2017Pwd!";
public final static String WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL="http-remoting://secserver.mydomain.com:28080";
```

After this the client was able to connect without any exceptions and the JMS messages started to flow.